# USB <> Serial(COM) port response time

Tags: serial-port, usb

Is any known solution how to speedup USB response time in Win7?
When I communicate with Usb.SerialPort I always have delay min 10ms for response. I suspect that issue is not serialport but USB communication in windows itself.

Comment: Which driver do you use? The FTDI driver has a *ton* of settings, some of which can improve latency.

Comment: My experiences with usb-serial ports are good. The one I tested was faster than the built-in serial port on the computer with Windows 7.